# UTF8 to equivalent number in php

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I've been searching my !!! off trying to find a PHP function to convert UTF8 to the equivalent number. I'm not entirely sure what to call the number (I heard its called an ordinate?) but heres an example: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/3040-309F

Basically I'm trying to read a UTF-8 .txt file in PHP and then save every line in an array, so I can mess around with it.

If anyone can assist me with this it would be highly appreciated, as I am not that familiar with UTF8 yet.

Edit:
This is what I've got so far:

```
echo "var TextCharacters = new Array();\n";

$LineArray = array();
$file_handle = fopen("lesson1.txt", "r");


while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{
  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);  
  array_push($LineArray, $line_of_text);
}

fclose($file_handle);

foreach($LineArray as $s)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($s,"utf-8"); $i++)
    {
        $char = mb_substr($s, $i, 1, "utf-8");
        echo "alert(go(" . bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2', $char)) . "));";         
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Unicode code points or UTF-8 byte representation?

Comment: See the comments at http://php.net/ord for various Unicode code point equivalents to `ord()`.

Comment: I mean the unicode code points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Unicode code point, i.e. the numeric identifier by which the character is known in the Unicode character table. The "cheapest" way to do this is through the UCS-2 character encoding, which maps 1:1 from bytes unto the Unicode code points:

```
echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2', 'あ'));
// 3042
```

Caveats: the returned code is always 4 hexadecimal digits long (which you may or may not like) and UCS-2 does not support characters higher than the BMP, i.e. higher than code point FFFF.

Comment: Thanks alot, deceze. This function is what I needed. All this UTF8 UNICODE UCS2 stuff was giving me a headache. I'm not sure yet what iconv does but I'll do some research in a moment.

Comment: `iconv` converts between different character sets. You may be interested in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for a primer.

Comment: I am having another problem. I read out the UTF-8 text file and I filled it up with the japanese character: あ. Now I have an array and each element of that array holds a line in my textfile. I want to convert each character individually to their code points so I used the str_split() function to split each sentence into an array of characters so I can convert them individually. Now when I echo each character it doesnt show the あ character, but when I echo the whole line it does. This probably means the str split function changes the value of each character.. How to fix this?

Comment: `str_split` is not multi-byte aware. It splits on individual *bytes*, not *characters*. See @fiskfisk's answer for how to loop over individual characters.

Comment: Hi dude. The looping works but only the standard ASCII characters show the right way (ABC etc.). When I look at the source code of the page once the browser finished loading it I see this weird character appear: ï»¿. Plus this is what happens to the foo text that fiskfisk came up with: fooÃ†Ã˜Ã…ã”ã–.

Comment: @user Sounds like an entirely different question, please don't make me answer that in a comment. Research "BOM" though.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing magic about UTF-8 in PHP. When you read the file, you'll get the byte values (and not parsed as characters). Iterate of the data you've read and use [ord()](http://no.php.net/ord) to get the decimal value of the byte.

If you want to do this with UTF-8 code points, you can use either [mb_substr](http://no.php.net/mb_substr) or [iconv_substr](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-substr.php) to extract each character before using ord() to print the value of each byte that makes up the character.

Update: To expand with a complete solution:

utf8.test: `fooÆØÅござ`

```
$utf8 = file_get_contents("utf8.test");

for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($utf8, "utf-8"); $i++)
{
    $char = mb_substr($utf8, $i, 1, "utf-8");

    print($char);
    print("\n");

    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($char); $j++)
    {
        print(dechex(ord($char[$j])));
    }

    print("\n\n");
}
```

Output:

```
f
66

o
6f

o
6f

Æ
c386

Ø
c398

Å
c385

ご
e38194

ざ
e38196
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Bytes are not Unicode code points though, which seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I modified my answer to also include a suggestion on how to get the utf-8 code points before your comment. Thanks for comment anyway. :-)

Comment: *"extract each character before using ord() to print the value of each byte"* still doesn't give you the *Unicode code point* of the character though...

Comment: I still dont get how I'm supposed to get the code points. First off I assume the code point means the code that resembles each character. Now I tried several functions on the ord() page of php.net but none of them retreived the code points that show on this link http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/3040-309F

Comment: An UTF code point is a location in the byte stream that indicates a new character. A UTF character may or may not consist of several bytes, and each collection of bytes which identifies a character is called a 'code point'. If your string is UTF-8 and you want to divide everything into explicit characters, you'll have to use mb_substr or iconv_substr() to extract each character, then use ord() on each byte in the character to print the values.

Comment: The OP expects the Unicode code point 3056 for "ざ", not the UTF-8 byte sequence `E3 81 96`.

Comment: OK, then I got confused by the way the question was worded about UTF-8.